# No Internet Connection in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet, ethernet, lts

I installed a fresh Ubuntu besides a Windows10 Installation.
In Windows Internet works fine. In Ubuntu I think I have ethernet connection, as I have an IP (from DHCP?) and also can ping IPs in the network. 
I tried really a lot but nothing works on that.
Here are some Outputs of Maybe Helpfull commands:

```
ifconfig

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:04:8c  
          inet addr:141.31.42.247  Bcast:141.31.43.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:220325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20845 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:211299782 (211.2 MB)  TX bytes:17066416 (17.0 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f0a00000-f0a20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:102353 (102.3 KB)  TX bytes:102353 (102.3 KB)
```

and

```
lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM [8086:15a0] (rev 05)
```

and

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 50:65:f3:41:04:8c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=141.31.42.247 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:29 memory:f0a00000-f0a1ffff memory:f0a3b000-f0a3bfff ioport:2040(size=32)
```

and

```
/etc/network/interfaces

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: it is possible that your card doesn't like the repo driver. unfortunately I can't point you to a better one

Comment: @ravery possible... but how do I check that?

Comment: @ravery it's listed as certified hardware for ubuntu here: https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201407-15336/

Comment: it may be certified for a card from intell, but manufactures tweak things. pre-installed cards may not exactly match the "out of the box card" from intell.

Comment: @ravery yes, but the workstation itself is certified

Comment: for which version? I've had driver updates and kernel updates break things. for example my current computer. had slow speed and kept restarting the connection every 3-5 minutes. using a different driver fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, network-manager is not currently managing your eno1 interface. 
To make this interface managed, add the following stanzas to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file,

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet auto
```

Then restart network-manager by doing the following. `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: did that. That added a connection called ifupdown(eno1) to the network manager. but when i click on it, it says you are now connected... and a few moments later:  Disconnected Ethernet Network

Comment: @Florian how big is the network you are connected to? what is your netmask?

Comment: subnetmask 255.255.252.0 in a medium sized university... I can't exactly tell you how much ips are around

Comment: in that case, the DHCP service in your network might be faulty. Have you noticed the Broadcast address in the output of `ifconfig`, 
 your broadcast address is 141.31.43.255 `Bcast:141.31.43.255` which seems to be out of your netmask. Bcast addresses are usually configured to be the last address in the subnet. You should configure your network manually.

Comment: Can I change that somehow? As I'm not the admin of the Network and the connection works in Windows